# QPrinter resolution is wrong in Linux

Tags: c++, linux, qt, printing, resolution

I am trying to get some image printing program to work in Qt. Trying to print to a custom printer for which  have the ppd. There are calculations based on the device information, to create the image to be sent to the printer.

When looking at the printer properties, I see that `Resolution` is `300 dpi x 300 dpi`.

In windows, everything works fine - but in Linux, the calculated image information becomes very large, making my files explode... Looking through all the data I found that in Linux, `physicalDpiX` and `physicalDpiY` (used in code calculation) are 1200 instead of 300.

So I blame it on the [QPrinter](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qprinter.html#QPrinter)::[PrinterMode](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qprinter.html#PrinterMode-enum)

> QPrinter::HighResolution  2   On Windows, sets the printer resolution to
>   that defined for the printer in use. For PostScript printing, sets the
>   resolution of the PostScript driver to 1200 dpi.

I changed my constructor to take care of it - just in case the defaults are wrong... It didn't work:

```
Printer::Printer(const QPrinterInfo& printerInfo, MainWindow* pWnd) :
#if defined(Q_OS_WIN32) || defined (Q_MAC_OSX)
    QPrinter(QPrinter::HighResolution)
#else
    QPrinter(QPrinter::ScreenResolution)
#endif
{
  qDebug()<<"printer resolution physicalDpiX="<< this->physicalDpiX()<<", physicalDpiY="<<this->physicalDpiY();
  // prints 1200 for each in Linux, 300 in windows
  qDebug()<<"printer resolution="<< this->resolution();
  // prints 96 in Linux, 300 in windows
  // printer properties (like from system-config-printer) show 300
  // printerInfo.printerName() and printerInfo.defaultPrinter().printerName() show my printer
}
```

the numbers are wrong for resolution in Linux, but correct in Windows

Tried

this->setResolution(300);

It made this.resolution() become 300, but physicalDpiX and Y show 1200 still.

[QPrinter::supportedResolutions ()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qprinter.html#supportedResolutions) seems to say that the case is hopeless...

How do I make my printer see the resolution shown in the Printer properties ?

Is the only hope to pull some methods from cups ? I tried... I don't understand how to use the only piece of information I found: [cups Resolution](http://www.cups.org/documentation.php/ref-ppdcfile.html#Resolution)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As much as I would like a generic answer to this question, for now I solved my problem for the specific drivers the user is expected to use, while leaving the defaults (1200) for other ones like pdf or hp printing...

My custom printer contains among the cups options, a resolution option that looks something like

```
name="printer-resolution" value="300x300dpi"
```

I can extract the resolution from it. If that specific cups option doesn't exist then I can use the default 1200.

Answer (score 3):

First, never rely on physical device resolution. User may use printers with different resolutions, print once with one resolution (300dpi), next time with other resolution (600dpi) or may print to the PDF file, or to open print preview window which uses screen resolution. Second, use ScreenResolution only for printing to the screen, for any high resolution device it is too much rough. Letters and images will be ugly and positioning on the page will be with too low precision.

Printing independent on a physical device resolution and operating system also, can be achieved with [QPainter](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qpainter.html) scaling. As far as I know, QPainter base resolution is 1200dpi. That means that is the finest effective resolution Qt can print. The next example shows how to set scaling before drawing any contents on the page.

```
QPrinter printer(QPrinter::HighResolution);
qreal resolutionFactor = 1200 / printer->resolution();
QPainter painter;
painter.begin(&printer);
painter.scale(1 / resolutionFactor, 1 / resolutionFactor);
printPage(&painter); // This method should implement printing itself
painter.end();
```

Then implement contents drawing (set x and y coordinates, width and height for images, etc) for base QPainter resolution of 1200dpi and rendering process will take care that all sizes will be automatically scaled to the resolution of the target device.

Comment: What you say is beautiful - unfortunately it only works in Windows. Printing to multiple devices, each with its own resolution, requires that the system must be able to recognize the resolution. The fact that Qt printing is unable to recognize the user/device resolution leads to problems such as mine: while the printer only supports 300 (very large scale printer, that works which giant images), the system will try to process something 16 times larger, leading to jobs that exceed the available memory (and even disk space on certain systems).

Comment: But... Your code snippet relies on the device resolution too... It unfortunately doesn't work, since "printer->resolution()" is wrong too

Comment: QPrinter::resolution() value is set by the driver, and if Linux driver always returns 1200, I guess it will additionally scale contents to physical resolution. I just tried to print something from Qt code on Windows and Linux (OpenSUSE, Samsung laser printer) and I got the same size of the output on paper in both cases. It is true that resolution() returns 1200 on Linux even if I print in 600dpi, but like I said, I am getting correct output on the paper.

Comment: You are getting the correct output - but the image sent to the printer is larger than it should be. And for REALLY LARGE images, this is a significant factor. That is why, printing on A4 on regular printers, I am leaving the default 1200. It is acceptable size. But multiply that by 16 and your printer will just give up.